# Юнит тестирование в java/Android

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты

Пытаюсь разобраться в юнит-тестировании в андроиде/java, зачем нужны где и как их применять.

**Вопросы:**

1. Какие классы нужно покрывать тестами ?
2. Что лучше всего(популярнее) для юнит-тестов в андроиде ?

Comment: все точно то же самое, как и в `Java`. Т. к. все "юниты" написаны на `java`, то и их тестирование проводится точ в точ, как для обычной `java`

Comment: @metalurgus, это понятно) но в java я не использовал юнит тесты тоже(

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы он был не про Android, а про Java. Это сделает его доступным для большего числа людей.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой вот фреймворк для юнит-тестов на андроиде: [Mockito](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html)

А вот, чтобы понять принципы юнит тестирования, стоит прочитать хоть какое-то количество статей\книг. Начните со статьи в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), походите по ссылкам в выдаче гугла по соответствующему запросу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Уже более-менее понял суть юнит тестов и интеграционных :) Ну и уже поюзал Robolectric, Espresso, JUnit 4)